# Error 404 in google_analytics_3 in R. lexical error: invalid char in json text

Tags: r, json, google-analytics

I have a problem with my code in R. I am trying to download data from Google Analytics with google_analytics_3 function. My code have been working until last week, but now it does not work.

I show my code:

```r
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(googleAuthR)

options(httr_oauth_cache=FALSE,
        googleAuthR.scopes.selected = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly")

gar_auth(email = myemail,
         cache = getOption("httr_oauth_cache"),
         scopes = getOption("googleAuthR.scopes.selected"))

dataAnalytics <- google_analytics_3(id = id,
                                    start = '2018-01-01',
                                    end = Sys.Date()-1,
                                    metrics = c('transactions'),
                                    dimensions = 'date',
                                    filters = paste0('ga:city==','madrid'),max_results = 10000)
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```r
Request Status Code: 404
Error : lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en> 
                     (right here) ------^

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/analytics/v3/data/ga/</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en> 
                     (right here) ------^
```

I do not know what is happening. Could you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This was a temporary bug caused by the change of the v3 API endpoint.  If you download the latest version of `googleAnalyticsR` from CRAN (0.7.1) then it is fixed.